# Firefox extension app hosted on server

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I managed to create a Chrome extension pretty easy and the main application is hosted on my server allowing me to provide updates to the app itself without having to update the whole extension. I like the idea and I just want to know if it's possible to create a similar extension for Firefox where the main application is hosted on a live server.

In creating my Chrome extension, I followed [a tutorial](http://www.sencha.com/blog/how-to-create-google-chrome-apps-and-extensions-from-your-ext-js-app/).  The code for Chrome is included on the linked page.

Comment: I have removed the code you included in the question.  The code appears to come from [this tutorial](http://www.sencha.com/blog/how-to-create-google-chrome-apps-and-extensions-from-your-ext-js-app/).  [The copyright notice in the terms of use](http://www.sencha.com/legal/terms-of-use/) for that site explicitly prohibits republishing the code in any form. Thus, it is not appropriate for inclusion here. I also looked in the [github repository](https://github.com/savelee/hosted-ext-chromeapp) and did not find a license that would permit republishing here.

Comment: The question strongly implies you are wanting to host the actual code for a Firefox extension on a live server and be able to dynamically update that code. This is not what is covered by the answer which you have accepted, nor the tutorial which is the source for the code originally included in your question. Both of those cover creating an extension that launches a web application. Your reverting the edit I had made to make this more clear, indicates that something I did was not desired. I'm sorry that was the case. Please update your question to reflect what you are actually asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to create a simple extension that loads a web app either in a panel or a tab. You should read up on the Addon SDK documentation, including the [panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel), [tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs) and [getting started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials#getting-started) docs.

There is nothing wrong with this, as the web app would not have direct access to internal Firefox APIs. If you read the Addon guidelines closely that @makyen links to above, none of it covers this implementation detail. In their defence, they seem to have misinterpreted what you want to do. It looks to me like you just want to integrate / launch your web app from the browser UI?

Answer (score 1):

***Web* application**:
After finding [the tutorial](http://www.sencha.com/blog/how-to-create-google-chrome-apps-and-extensions-from-your-ext-js-app/) (please provide a link next time) I surmise you are referring to in your question, I suspect that what you are actually attempting to convey is different than how I initially interpreted your question. I have edited the question to make this more clear to people reading it in the future.

That tutorial is explaining how to place a link to a *web* application into the Chrome user interface. Such is, to a large extent, just a bookmark that is able to be placed within other areas of the user interface than the bookmarks bar.

If that is what you are wanting to do, then, yes, you can easily do so in Firefox. Given that the extension is not running external content in the security context of an extension (you are effectively just navigating to and displaying a website), then that should be fine as a Firefox extension. Note that you need to be sure that you are not granting elevated permissions when you launch the web application.

If running a web application is what you are wanting to do, then I suggest you might want to use different semantics to refer to what you are doing.  The above is not a "Firefox extension app hosted on server". Saying it that way strongly implies that you are hosting the actual extension code on your own server. The rest of your question implies that the extension dynamically loads external code and runs it. I would suggest that you refer to it as something like: a web application that is launched (navigated to) by a Firefox extension allowing the web application to be started from an icon in the toolbar.

**Extension running web sourced code:**
However, if what you are wanting to do is have external content running as a Firefox extension, then implementing that functionality is a large security hole for anyone installing the extension.  Even assuming that your intentions are totally benign, there is a huge security hole for anyone who is intercepting your traffic, or gains control of your server to inject code into Firefox that runs at the level of an extension (i.e. the malware can have *full* control of the browser and then of the computer).

Yes, it is currently possible for you to write this for Firefox.

However, given that the extension pulls code from something not packaged within the extension, the extension will never be permitted to be hosted on [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/).

In addition, the plan is that later this year [there will be mandatory signing of Firefox extensions through Mozilla](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/02/10/extension-signing-safer-experience/). I doubt that an extension like this will be permitted at that time.

You can read a set of [Add-on guidelines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_guidelines) on MDN.